# Random behavior with Pointer de-referencing in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, dereference

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int myvar = 5;
    int * p;
    cout << "Hello2" << endl;

    *p = myvar;
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    cout << p << endl;
    //cout << &myvar << endl;
}
```

I know I am not doing the right thing by not initializing the pointer. I was just playing with pointers and noticed this. The issue is when I comment out the last line, the program executes normally. But as soon as I uncomment the line, I get a segmentation fault. I don't know why printing address of myvar is causing this? Has myvar been modified in any way because of pointer dereferencing? I am using C++11.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Pointers only work when they point to something.

Comment: MSVC 2012 won't build this, with or without the last line.

Answer (score 0):

```
int* p;
*p = myvar;
```

You are creating an uninitialized pointer and then derferencing that pointer. This has undefined behavior because `p` has to point to something for it to be derferenced correctly. Therefore your program's behavior can't be reasoned with.

Comment: I realize I am not doing the correct thing by not initializing the pointer. The point is I have run this many times and g++ only gives segmentation fault when I put in the last line and not when I comment it out. I find this surprising as I did not expect any change to happen to the myvar variable. It should be printing the address of myvar always I guess.

Comment: @YogeshRane, "Therefore your program's behavior can't be reasoned with." It's true, undefined behaviour can even include [time travel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/27/10537746.aspx).

Comment: @YogeshRane My guess is that the compiler is eliminating the pointer code entirely since it has no observable effect. Since you're printing `&myvar` the compiler will then have to compile the part the gives a segmentation fault. Try running with optimizations turned off to see a potential difference. But again, this could just be an effect of undefined behavior so we can't be certain.

Comment: @0x499602D2 On coliru's gcc, the effect of this UB-program is quite well reproducible. The `*p = myvar` is not eliminated as far as I can tell, but something with the offsets to rbp is different, though I can't really tell what since I can't see the allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation Fault occurs when trying to access a virtual memory address that has no read permissions.

In your case, the local variable `p` holds uninitialized garbage from the stack.
you are dereferencing a memory address that might not be readable(e.g no read permissions, hence the segmentation fault when trying to access it).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure the purpose of your snippet, but the following code will work, and perhaps it will help:

```
int myvar = 5;
int *p = nullptr;
p = &myvar;
cout << myvar << endl;
cout << &myvar << endl;
cout << p << endl;
cout << *p << endl;
```

*(Note:  I used two lines for setting 'p' because that is how you did it in your snippet.  You could easily just use: int *p = &myvar; )*

Anyway, there are scope issues here as p will only be valid as long as myvar is in scope; however, this does illustrate the basics of pointers.   myvar and *p will return the same value (the value being pointed to), and &myvar and p will return the same value (the location of value in memory.)